# recursive SQL with an aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

UPDATE:

Please note that I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858107/aggregate-function-in-recursive-sql), and so this question can be considered closed/answered as well.

So, I am a newbie to recursive SQL (I work with Oracle). I am trying to solve this specific equation in SQL (I follow LaTeX notation below):

```
U^{F,D}_{t,p} = [\sum_{D}( U^{F,D}_{t-1,p}*BPX^{F}_{t} ) + C_{t-1,p}]*R^{F,D}_{t-1,p}*(1/BPX^{F}_{t})
```

which result in

[image]

In words: it is an iterative equation, you are given `U^{F,D}_{t=0,p}` (think of `t` as of time), and your task is to roll it forward, for `t>0`.

The SQL data might look like in [this fiddle that I link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3237c/66). So, all the other variables/data used in the equation are already there, computed, so that on `t` it is only `U^{F,D}_{t>0,p}` that one does not know. The task is to take them from `t` (or `t-1`, if the equation above says so), and use to compute `U^{F,D}_{t>0,p}`.

To this end, I have come up with the recursive query in [the fiddle linked above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3237c/66) that I paste also here for reference:

```
--
-- T    -> t
-- T_M1 -> t-1
-- e.g.:
-- BPX_T -> BPX^{F}_{t}, etc.
--
WITH RECU(  T, T_M1, T_MAX, P, F, DELTA_F, BPX_T, 
            R_T_M1, C_T_M1, U_T_M1, 
            R_T, C_T, U_T ) AS (
    -- Anchor member.
    SELECT  T,
            T_M1, T_MAX,
            P, 
            F, DELTA_F, 
            BPX_T,
            R_T_M1, C_T_M1, 
            U_T_M1, 
            R_T, C_T, 
            U_T
    FROM DYNAMICS 
        -- Initial condition: U_{t-1} does not exist, and U_{t=0} is given
        WHERE  ( U_T_M1 IS NULL AND U_T IS NOT NULL )
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member.
    SELECT  NEW.T,
            NEW.T_M1, NEW.T_MAX, 
            NEW.P, 
            NEW.F, NEW.DELTA_F, 
            NEW.BPX_T, 
            NEW.R_T_M1, NEW.C_T_M1, 
            -- NEW.U_T_M1,
            RECU.U_T AS U_T_M1,
            NEW.R_T, NEW.C_T, 
            -- NEW.U_T
            ((RECU.U_T*NEW.BPX_T)+NEW.C_T_M1)*(NEW.R_T_M1/NEW.BPX_T) AS U_T
    FROM DYNAMICS NEW 
    INNER JOIN RECU
    ON
        -- Translates: yesterday (t-1) of the new record equals today (t) of the parent record      
        NEW.T_M1 = RECU.T AND 
        NEW.P = RECU.P AND 
        NEW.F = RECU.F AND 
        NEW.DELTA_F = RECU.DELTA_F 
)
SELECT * FROM  RECU ORDER BY P, F, T;
```

(where D in the original mathematical equation above corresponds to DELTA in the SQL query).

So, the above is now working, as one can check in the fiddle. The problem is that I have cheated, taking for input data only DELTAs (Ds) always with one value 0.0, whereas what the original mathematical equations says is that I should allow different values of DELTAs (Ds), and that I should sum over them (`\sum_{D}`) for a given `t`. So, in order to do that, I would need to have some sort of `GROUP BY/SUM` expression in the query above, but I have no clue how to squeeze that in so that my recursion would not get hurt.

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Sample data and desired results are much more widely understood than esoteric function syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff They had been provided in the link to the fiddle

Comment: Is it possible to simplify or remove some parts of the formula while still demonstrating the problem?